# Using WSL2 directories in R

Tags: r, windows, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I'm using Windows Subsystem Linux 2 (**WSL2**) in Windows 10 and it works perfectly from the Ubuntu Terminal.

I want to work some files inside the **WSL2**' directory `(//wsl.localhost/Ubuntu/home/forever/tesis/)` using **WSL2** from **R**.

So, I tested the functionality of wsl using the `shell()` function in **R**.

```
shell(cmd = "cd")
# C:\Users\ivanl\Documents
```

it works perfect, but when I tried to access the **WSL2**' directories it return errors

```
shell(cmd = "cd //wsl.localhost/Ubuntu/home/forever/tesis/")
# El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada.
# In shell(cmd = "cd //wsl.localhost/Ubuntu/home/forever/tesis/") :
#    'cd //wsl.localhost/Ubuntu/home/forever/tesis/' execution failed with error code 1


shell(cmd = "cd /mnt/c")
# El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada.
# Warning message:
# In shell(cmd = "cd /mnt/c") :
#    'cd /mnt/c' execution failed with error code 1
```

*El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada* means "The system can not find the specified path"

The next example doesn't return an error, but it stay processing forever, and it force me to stop it.

```
shell( cmd = "wsl cd /mnt/c/home/forever/tesis")
```

If I try to access the **WSL2**' directory `(//wsl.localhost/Ubuntu/home/forever/tesis/)` from **R** (not using `shell()`) there is no problem, I can read, modify files and all works fine.

I'm out of ideas to solve this, hope you can help me.

Comment: Is that the Windows version of R or is it installed in WSL?  From the way things are worded, it sounds like it's the Windows version, but I want to make sure.

Comment: Windows version of R (and RStudio)

Answer (score 1):

Some theory, some experience here.  Taking an education guess at the first part - As it is, I believe that Windows R is calling CMD for the `shell()`.  This is evidenced by the fact that `cd` is return the current directory in your "working" example.  Only CMD does this - PowerShell returns a noop with just a
`cd`.

With that in mind, the problem you are experiencing is probably because CMD does not support UNC paths (even though R itself does).

Possible solutions (untested, since I don't have R installed):

- Map the WSL share to a drive letter.  The mapping will need to go to the top-level share (e.g., `\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu`) rather than the subdirectory itself.  The shared drive letter will be accessible from CMD (and thus, hopefully, R).
- Set your shell to PowerShell.  From reading the [`shell()` doc](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.1/topics/shell), this might look something like:

  ```r
  shell(cmd = "cd //wsl.localhost/Ubuntu/home/forever/tesis/; get-childitem", shell = "pwsh.exe")
  # or
  shell(cmd = "cd //wsl.localhost/Ubuntu/home/forever/tesis/; get-childitem", shell = "powershell.exe")
  # or perhaps
  shell(cmd = "cd //wsl.localhost/Ubuntu/home/forever/tesis/; get-childitem", shell = "C:/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe")
  ```

The last command, where you attempt to start WSL directly, *may* be failing because R automatically sets the flag for the shell to be `/c` (assuming, again that it is CMD or Bash).  The WSL command doesn't have a `/c` flag itself.

If you want to try to execute WSL directly, try something like:

```r
shell(cmd = "cd /home/forever/tesis/; pwd; ls", shell = "wsl.exe", flags = "-e bash -c")
# or potentially
shell(cmd = "cd /home/forever/tesis/; pwd; ls", shell = "wsl.exe", flags = "")
```